# Accessing nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to run some JavaScript, but it is not working.

I have an object with two properties that are also objects.

```
var people = {
        me: {
            name: "Hello"
        },

        molly: {
            name: "Molly"
        }
    };
```

And I am trying to make a function that uses a for/in statement and an if statement to list the properties of people.

```
var search = function (x) {
        for (var a in people) {
            if (people.a.name === x) {
                return people.a;
            }
        }
    };
```

So the function loops through the properties of people and assigns them to the variable a.  Therefore people.a will be equal to a property of people.  Then the function returns the property (people.a).

So if I type in me as parameter x, will the function should return the properties for the me object?  I put this code in jsLint and jsHint and it passed, but I decided to remove the corrections because they were useless.

I then want to print the object properties in the browser:

```
var print = search("me");
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML(print);
```

I have this linked to an html document, with a

tag id "p".  I have tested javascript in the html document already, so I know that the javascript document is linked properly.

But the code will not work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have it working now thanks to the answers.  But I thought that it would only print "Hello" to the screen, not { name: "Hello"}.

Comment: With your example, `search("me")` wouldn't return anything because there aren't any people with `name: "me"`. Maybe you meant `search("Hello")`. Either way, there is another problem and the answers below describe that...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `people[a]`, not `people.a`.  The former looks for a property with the name of the value stored in `a`; the latter looks for a property literally named "a", which of course doesn't exist.

```
for (var a in people) {
    if (people[a].name === x) {
        return people[a];
    }
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/5PJ6v/3/)

Also, I think you meant `search("Hello")`, right?  If not, then it would just be `var search = function(x) { return people[x]; }`.

Comment: Yes I did mean search("Hello").  So if the properties of an object are an object I need to use [ ] instead of . ?  Also, if I added more properties to the me object would this code also print them onto the screen?

Comment: @user2620463 - if I understand your statement about "properties of an object are an object", that isn't correct.  If you are trying to access the property of an object using the *value* of a variable, *then* you need to use bracket notation.   In this case, when the variable `a === "me"`, `people[a]` is equivalent to `people["me"]` is equivalent to `people.me`

Answer (score 1):

```
people.a.name
```

you need to use the bracket operator if you want to access an item by name.  Using `people.a` is literally searching for a member named 'a' instead of a member with the same name as the value of `a`.

Try:

```
people[a].name
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

4 errors in your code:

- replace `people.a` with `people[a]`
- replace `innerHTML()` with `innerHTML`
- set HTML like this: `document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = print.name;`
- As in a previous answer, search by name

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/vVSPG/

Comment: Thank!  This is exactly what I wanted to do.  Do I only use [ ] if the property is another object?

Comment: You would use obj.a or obj['a'] if if the object has the property a that you are interested in.